# I don't understand a Try Catch Exception part of code

Tags: c#

On a project, I found this part of code :

```
public String EndDateText
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                if (_endDate != null)
                    return _endDate.Value.ToString("o");
                else
                    return "";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _endDate = new DateTimeOffset();
                throw;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                _endDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand the line *_endDate = new DateTimeOffset();* in catch part.

Why it create a new instance of the _endDate ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Mostly because someone wrote poor code. Probably a race condition might lead to a NullReferenceException

Comment: I believe the person write the code just want to "reset" the value of the _endDate by isntance a new 1

Comment: Yes, the only realistic way `_endDate.Value.ToString("o");` could throw an exception is if some other thread sets `_endDate` to null inbetween the `if (_endDate != null)` check and the `return _endDate.Value.ToString("o");`. So as /u/CSharpie said, probably bad code in a miguided attempt to fix a thread-related problem.